# How to access variables in main.cpp from function in mainwindow.cpp?

Tags: c++, qt

I click button and want change some variables in main.cpp. How access it from function in mainwindow.cpp.

```
void MainWindow::on_spinBox_valueChanged(int coef)
{
   //here I need x=coef;
   //x is in main.cpp
}
```

Comment: You'ĺl have to add a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: However the idea about accessing/writting variables inside the main does not sound very good

Comment: You'll need to improve your design. Your MainWindow class, as any class, should not touch or even know about anything outside of its limits. So whatever you want to do with that `x` should go through some interfacing mechanism. It can be very simple or very complex depending on your use case, but we have no information here on the intent.

Comment: Can you give some example? All I need is to pass this coef from form to x( main.cpp variable)

Comment: I fully agree with @spectras, your design sounds a bit messy. However, if you really want to go this route, you can pass a pointer to x to the MainWindow and update that pointer's value in your button's slot function, As said by others, I would rather double check your design. If you share some details, I am sure there is a better solution to your actual problem...

Comment: use `extern variable`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, it is better to change the architecture of your program. However, if you still want to opt for a simple solution, you can use the external variables:

Declare `x` in your file `main.cpp` out of main function:

```
#include ...  

int x;

int main ()...
```

In your `mainwindow.cpp`, declare your `x` as `extern` in global scope:

```
extern int x;  
void MainWindow::on_spinBox_valueChanged(int coef) 
{
   x = coef;
}
```

Comment: I don't think suggesting `extern` as first choice is a good idea (actually I can't think of any where `extern` should be used - one should rather add setter to the MainWindow class)